# Learn Asp.net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm Looking for a good project source samples for learning ASP.NET MVC 2. (Full project like CMS, Blog...anything that is well written in MVC2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Starter Site](http://mvcstarter.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3):

[Nerd Dinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) is very good. The current release is MVC1, but it's in the progress of being upgraded to MVC2 and the code for it is already available.

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out the [Orchard Project](http://www.orchardproject.net/). It's a CMS with blog features.

It's in a quite early stage, but it has a very clear roadmap and many talented developers are working on this project.

Answer (score 1):

This blog by ScottGu is very nice.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/14/asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx

Comment: -1 , He asked for open source projects.

Comment: I can't see any reference to open source - just for project source, by which I assume he means sample source code?

Answer (score 1):

The [source code](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) for the book [ASP .NET MVC in Action](http://www.manning.com/palermo/), which is 99%-100% MVC 2 at this point, demonstrates a well written MVC 2 app.

Answer (score 1):

I've been putting together a project to demonstrate MVC2 features for an upcoming talk I'm giving.  It's a work in progress, but I've covered 80% of the good stuff.

http://bitbucket.org/stevehorn/mvc2-features-demo

Answer (score 0):

[Nerd dinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) tutorial is really good for learning MVC even if it's based on MVC 1. Since MVC 2 is still fresh then you probably won't find any "full projects" based on this release for some time, however there are series devoted to MVC 2 on [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) which you can apply as you go through Nerd dinner stuff.